# getRelatedListRecords sortBy direction

Tags: lightning-web-components

Is there a way to specify the sort direction in the `getRelatedListRecords` wire adapter?

The [Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reference-wire-adapters-get-related-list-records.html) give the following example:

```
@wire(getRelatedListRecords, {
  parentRecordId: '001RM000003UNu6YAG',
  relatedListId: 'Contacts',
  fields: ['Contact.Name','Contact.Id'],
  sortBy: ['Contact.Name']
})
```

But there's no documentation on how to define the `sortBy` as ASC or DESC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_requests_related_list_record_input.htm) documentation, You need to pass the `-` before the field name to get data in descending order.

*If the name is preceded by `-`, the sort order is **descending**.
For example, **Name** sorts by name in ascending order. **-CreatedDate** sorts by created date in descending order.*

```
@wire(getRelatedListRecords, {
        parentRecordId: "001RM000003UNu6YAG",
        relatedListId: 'Contacts',
        fields: ['Contact.Name', 'Contact.Id'],
        sortBy: ['-Contact.Name']
    })
    listInfo({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            console.log("data:: " + JSON.stringify(data.records));
        } else if (error) {
            console.log("error:: " + JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    }
```